# Mysqldump - Importar fichero SQL

Tags: mysql

He exportado una base de datos desde un servidor Linux con el comando:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p kiosko > kiosko.sql
```

Me lo he traído a mi máquina en local y lo he ejecutado de esta forma:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqldump -uroot kiosko < "c:\temp\sql_testing\kiosko.sql"
```

Me sale esto por pantalla:

```
-- MariaDB dump 10.17  Distrib 10.4.8-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: kiosko
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       10.4.8-MariaDB

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS,
FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2020-01-17 12:52:31

C:\xampp\mysql\bin>
```

Si miro el contenido del fichero SQL (no lo pondré entero porque son 100 MiB) pero las primeras líneas son como estas.

Comment: Para importar debes usar `mysql` y no `mysqldump`. La instrucción `mysqldump` se usa únicamente para exportar los datos y con la instrucción `mysql` los importas. Lo que estás haciendo en tu ejemplo es exportar (y no importar) los datos de tu máquina local, por eso sale un volcado vacío de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para importar deberías ejecutar `mysql -uroot -p kiosko < kiosko.sql`

Comment: muchas gracias.

Answer (score 6):

Para importar debes usar `mysql` y no `mysqldump`. La instrucción `mysqldump` se usa únicamente para exportar los datos y con la instrucción `mysql` los importas. Lo que estás haciendo en tu ejemplo es exportar (y no importar) los datos de tu máquina local, por eso sale un volcado vacío de datos.

La instrucción correcta sería:

```
mysql -uroot kiosko -p < "c:\temp\sql_testing\kiosko.sql"
```

Comment: tambien puede usar [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html)

Comment: teneis razón, 1000 gracias a los dos